# Does CCSM work with Gnome-shell?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gnome

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 and now that gnome-shell is "safe" to install, I thought I'd give it another go.
After a small driver issue, gnome-shell is working great!

I am a big fan of the compiz "Grid" plugin - specifically the alt+ctrl+kp_* bindings.
According to ccsm, they are set, but they do not work. Dragging windows to the sides work, but the keyboard shortcuts do not.  Then I realised that none of the changes I make via CCSM are taking effect!

Does this mean gnome-shell does not work with CCSM or is this just something wrong with my system?

Any ideas on how I can make this work again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CCSM (short for CompizConfig Settings Manager) lets you configure the settings of Compiz. Unity is a plugin of Compiz whereas gnome-shell is a plugin of mutter. That's why changes made using CCSM doesn't have any effect on gnome-shell.

If you want to customize gnome-shell, you can try [gnome-tweak-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool) [image: Install gnome-tweak-tool]. To install it, search for 'gnome-tweak-tool' in the software center or by running this command in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

You can also try the gnome-shell extensions that let you customize the various features of gnome-shell. To try out these extensions, visit the official [gnome-shell extensions site](https://extensions.gnome.org/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.
If this isn't using compiz at all, is there a way of configuring the "mutter" plugin so I can discover/modify keyboard shortcuts?
I have gnome-tweak-tool, but it doesn't have that many options.

Comment: @SteveOcchipinti Right now, I don't think there are any mutter configuring managers around. Some tools that may help are the above-mentioned gnome-tweak-tool, dconf-tools and gconf-editor. If you want to see available keyboard shortcuts for gnome-shell, you can search for 'keyboard' settings in the applications overview and view shortcuts tab in that window. You can also take a look at this [official Gnome-shell shortcuts cheatsheet](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet).

Comment: Thanks very much for the tips, those resources are very helpful.
I found some more settings in gconf under /apps/metacity/window_keybindings, but I guess the "grid" functionality is a lot more basic in mutter.
Appreciate you help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This shell extension seems to do the trick. Put Window:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is very important](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This prevents linkrot and old documentation from creeping in.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome shell does provide A convenient way to edit keyboard shortcuts - in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I found this neat script [gnome-shell-grid](https://github.com/paulswartz/gnome-shell-grid) It seems to work well, atleast with a single monitor setup. Im currently trying to figure out how to make it work for my twinview setup using the restricted nvidia driver.