# Mouse trails for GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, mouse, accessibility

I'm trying to prepare my laptop (trusty, `gnome-shell`) for use in **presentations**. As such, I'll need to do something to make the mouse more visible.

1) There's [a program for Windows](http://www.pointerfocus-for-presenters.com/how-to-highlight-mouse-pointer.html) that does that well.
2) There's a workaround on `gnome-tweak-tool` to locate the mouse by pressing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.

3) There's a [workaround on `ccsm`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370344/is-there-a-mouse-trail-option) that can act as alternative to mouse trails, but of course [it doesn't work on GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68475/does-ccsm-work-with-gnome-shell).

So far, none of the above looked practical for general presentations from gnome-shell.

**Question: Is there a way to have a nice presentation cursor with GNOME Shell?**

(even if it's just a mouse trail)
(better if it'll look like No. 1)

Lots of thanks!

PS: The only mouse cursor set I ever liked in Linux is [Oxygen](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=oxygen-cursor) for KDE. [;-)](http://lavalon.deviantart.com/art/Oxygen-Cursors-76614092)

Comment: As a workaround, you could increase the mouse pointer's size with gnome-tweak-tool, so it's better visible.